# I'm getting "group function is nested too deeply" when I run the below sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I know I'm missing something here as I cannot use an aggregate-able function (or in this case double aggregate-able function in Sum(count...)) in a where function, but can't seem to figure out how to re-write the sql.

```
SELECT city,
       state,
       COUNT(studentID),
       COUNT(instructorID)
FROM   Student
       JOIN Instructor
       ON Student.ZIP= Instructor.ZIP
WHERE  SUM(COUNT(studentID), COUNT(instructorID)) AS TOTAL >= 10
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

The sql is supposed to List all cities that have 10 or more students and instructors combined. Show city, state, number of student residents, number of instructor residents, and total student/instructor residents in that city. Sort by total in descending order.

I appreciate any help I could get... Thanks!

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Also read some introductions on how sum/aggregates work--they use group by, which if not explicit is implicit; they can't appear in where (where they don't make sense); they can appear in having or select; they don't nest; you might want aggregation in subquery. Also your issues are faqs, which you would probaby find if you googled many clear precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal/issue.

Comment: @jaggsharry . . . What do the tables look like?

Comment: I'm glad there are some here that (still) are actually 'SOreadytohelp'. Bravo, @Gordon Linoff & MT0!!

Answer (score 2):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause if you are using aggregation functions with non-aggregated columns. You also cannot define aliases in the `WHERE` clause and if you want to filter on aggregation functions then you either want to use `HAVING` clause or perform the aggregation in a sub-query.

Something like:

```
SELECT city,
       state,
       COUNT(studentID),
       COUNT(instructorID)
FROM   Student
       JOIN Instructor
       ON Student.ZIP = Instructor.ZIP
GROUP BY
       city,
       state
HAVING COUNT(studentID) + COUNT(instructorID) >= 10
ORDER BY
       COUNT(studentID) + COUNT(instructorID) DESC;
```

It doesn't show the "total student/instructor residents in that city" but since this appears to be homework, that is left as an exercise to complete.

Comment: Thanks MT0! Yes, I can derive the total student/instructor residents in that city from this!

Answer (score 0):

You would need the proper `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` clauses.  More importantly, though, you need the proper query for the results to mean anything.

Assuming both tables have `city` and `state`:

```
select city, state, sum(student) as student, sum(instructor) as instructor
from ((select city, state, 1 as student, 0 as instructor
       from student
      ) union all
      (select city, state, 0 as student, 1 as instructor
       from instructor
      )
     ) si
group by city, state
having sum(student) + sum(instructor) >= 10
order by sum(student) + sum(instructor) desc;
```

A `join` on the unaggregated data is simply not going to return the right results.

EDIT:

Based on the comment, the correct query would be:

```
select z.city, z.state, sum(si.student) as student, sum(si.instructor) as instructor
from ((select zip, 1 as student, 0 as instructor
       from student
      ) union all
      (select zip, 0 as student, 1 as instructor
       from instructor
      )
     ) si join
     zipcode z
     on z.zip = si.zip
group by z.city, z.state
having sum(ai.student) + sum(si.instructor) >= 10
order by sum(si.student) + sum(si.instructor) desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I forgot to add the table structure, but I have a Zipcode table with City, State and Zip; Student table with StudentID, Zip, First & Last Name, and Instructor table with InstructorID, Zip, First and Last Name. I know I can join all 3 tables on the common key 'Zip' and get my desired result using this as a guide. Thanks again!